# Spring Integration nullChannel reference in Non-DSL

Tags: spring-integration

We have a dynamic `IntegratonFlow` registration using `IntegrationFlowContext`. For an conditional use-case we need to set the `replyChannel` with reference to Spring Integration Context's `nullChannel` object. How do I get the `MessageChannel` reference of framework created `nullChannel` object?

Will `MessageChannels.direct(IntegrationContextUtils.NULL_CHANNEL_BEAN_NAME).getObject()` provide me the framework created `nullChannel` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not. The default `nullChannel` is an instance of `NullChannel`.
I'm not sure why you need to deal with `MessageChannels` factory, but there is just enough to have that `nullChannel` to be auto-wired into the service you are going to use it. Or just rely on a `nullChannel` string as is and the framework will be able to resolve it properly.

Otherwise, please, share more info about your configuration, and we will look what more specific solution would fit into your requirements.

Comment: Thanks Artem, autowiring nullChannel did the job